# Itextsharp which styles support HtMLWorker?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I know that HTMLWorker supports inline CSS styles, but I can't find which. Which style sheet is it can read and parse to pdf? I didn't find it in documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: You can find it in the source code. Unfortunately `HTMLWorker` is so old that you won't find any other documentation. I recommend that you use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: I have got problem with XMLWorker. If some tags not closed, that it can parse html file no right, or don't parse file.

Comment: That means your HTML is invalid. First send your HTML through a cleanup tool like JSoup/NSoup to get clean HTML before you give it to XMLWorker.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, sorry, but what can you advise from clean up tools for my problem besides NSoup?

Comment: Well, if you wait a couple of weeks, then a new add-on for iText 7 will be released, which uses JSoup under the hood, and which is much more robust for invalid HTML.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, But I use `ITextsharp` for `c#`... If it will be in itextsharp, that much later. What can I trying use now?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, can I use next project for solving my problem?  https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged

Comment: iText 7 releases for Java and for .NET are released on the same day. We strive to have iText 5 releases for .NET (also known as iTextSharp) to be within a day of the release of iText 5 Java. But I am unsure if this answers your question.

Comment: That's up to you to decide. As long as you feed XMLWorker valid HTML, it is happy, and it doesn't care how you get that valid HTML.